# Optimal size for a ring buffer with single producer and single consumer

Tags: real-time, microcontroller, rtos, circular-buffer

I have a single producer, single consumer problem which (I believe) can be solved using a circular/ring buffer.

I have a micro-controller running a RTOS, with an ISR(Interrupt Service Routine) handling UART (Serial port) interrupts. When the UART raises an interrupt, the ISR posts the received characters into the circular buffer. In another RTOS task (called packet_handler), I am reading from this circular buffer and running a state machine to decode the packet. A valid packet has 64 bytes including all the framing bytes.

The UART operates at 115200, and a packet arrives every 10ms. The packet_handler runs every 10ms. However, this handler may sometimes get delayed by the scheduler due to another higher priority task executing.

If I use an arbitrarily large circular buffer, there are no packet drops. But how to determine the optimal circular buffer size in this case? At least theoretically. How is this decision of buffer size made in practice?

Currently, I am detecting overrun of the buffer through some instrumentation functions and then increasing the buffer size to reduce packet loss.

Comment: Your packet handler must have a cycle time < 10ms. Remember that the 10ms on the receiver CPU aren't 10ms on the sender CPU and therefore they are asymptotically drifting away from each other (assuming that there is no other sync mechanism). If your packet_handler processes only one packet and your sender runs slightly faster than the receiver, you will *always* run out of memory, no matter how large the buffer. This is just Shannon in disguise :)

Comment: Ok. I can change the periodicity of packet_handler after taking into account the maximum clock drift of the sender with respect to receiver. Further i will reduce the time period of packet_handler a bit more so that the receiver is always running at a slightly faster pace than transmitter. Now is the problem solvable using a finite buffer?

Comment: Is the buffer in question a packet buffer or a character buffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While all of the above answers are correct and throws light on the issue, [this page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/375321/efficient-size-of-fifo-buffer-for-uart) summarizes all the factors to be considered while choosing the size of a ring buffer.

Some queuing models can be used to theoretically analyze the problem at hand and find out the suitable size of ring buffer.

A more pragmatic approach is to start with a large buffer, then find out the maximum used buffer size in real test case (this process is called watermarking) and use this figure in the final code.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be safe, ever, as you are dealing with a stochastic process (according to your explanation).
Answering your question: You will need an infinite buffer just in case the consumer task is in ready state for infinite seconds. So, you will have to change something in your initial approach:

- Increase the priority of the consumer, in order to ensure the 10ms execution (the smallest buffer approach, but it may not be possible).
- Try to get a better characterization of your model, in order to predict the maximum gap of time in which the consumer task won't be executed (do your system as predictable as possible).
- Lose packages with a random buffer size (it may not be safe)

Comment: Ok. So if know the worst case execution time of all tasks in the system and their priorities, Is this information sufficient to calculate the required buffer size? There are no sporadic jobs (unpredictable) in the system.

Comment: Yes, but the buffer size could be infinite. The consumer should be able to read more than one package per call too.

Comment: Assuming that all other tasks have higher priority than packet_handler, and their worst case execution time is known, i can calculate the max time interval for which packet_handler will be blocked. Further, i can modify my packet_handler to process as many packets as there are in buffer in one invocation of  it. Given these two conditions ( maximum blocking time, and packet_handler being able to process multiple packets in one call), can there be a solution with finite buffer size?

Comment: Assuming that you have calculated the worst case and it is something like: PPCPPCPPCPP (being C the consumer and P the producer), you still need an infinite buffer:  [P(64B) C(0B) P(64B) P(128B) C(64B) P(128B) P(192B) C(128B) P(192B) P(256B) C(192B) P(256B) P(320B)] (the producer is +64B and the consumer is -64B), so the consumer has to read as many packages as the relation between the consumer and the producer.

Comment: I mean, if the producer is two times faster, the consumer will have to read almost twice the amount of packages: [P(64B) C(0B) P(64B) P(128B) C(0B) P(64B) P(128B) C(0B) P(64B) P(128B) C(0B) P(64B) P(128B)] (the producer is +64B Band the consumer is -128B). Here, a 128B buffer is enough.

Comment: Putting things concrete -- I have two periodic tasks T1 and T2 other than the packet_handler task (T3). T1 is scheduled to occur periodically every 50ms and has a worst case execution period of 10ms. T2 is scheduled to occur periodically every 100ms and has a worst case execution period of 10ms.

Comment: Now , the tasks T1, T2 and T3 (all the tasks in the system) has a hyperperiod (the time interval after which the scheduling pattern repeats) of 100ms ( Least Common Multiplier of period of T1, T2 and T3). So tasks T1 and T2 will be scheduled together at time intervals like 0ms, 100ms, 200ms etc. During these periods T3(which has least priority) will be blocked for 20ms (Worst case exec time for T1 + Worst case exec time for T2).

Comment: So by the time T3 is scheduled, there are already two full packets received and there should be buffer space for one more packet. So a buffer space for 4 packets is safe enough i guess. Am i going wrong somewhere here?

Comment: If your task with a 10ms deadline can be delayed by more than 10ms that perhaps your task priorities need reconsideration.  Priority is not a matter of importance, but of run-time and deadlines.  But that is perhaps a different question.

Answer (score 0):

I would calculate in this way:

64 Byte received just know
64 Byte still in the ring buffer
+100% to be save
 ===================
256 Byte Buffer

But this is just a guess. You had to do some worst case test with your buffer and then spend +100% to be save.

Comment: Two slots(of 64bytes each) in the buffer would be enough if the packet_handler is very punctual and comes up exactly at 10ms intervals (as there is one packet every 10ms). But the problem here is that the packet_handler gets pre-empted due to other high priority tasks.

Comment: I guess iam losing packets due to jitter in the time at which packet_handler is scheduled.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply a matter of determining the maximum possible delay - the sum of the execution times of all higher priority tasks that can run - and dividing that by the packet arrival interval.

This may not be straightforward, but can be simplified by making only the most deterministic tasks higher priority and moving less deterministic and longer running tasks to lower priorities according to rate-monotonic principles  Tasks that frequently run for a short time, but sporadically run for longer are candidates for being split into two tasks (and further queues) to offload the longer execution to a lower priority.